# How to Render Cylinder with built in function D3DXCreateCylinder in Directx9 with Delphi-Xe2 and JEDI?

Tags: directx, directx9, delphi

I'm new to Directx and i want to render Cylinder using "D3DXCreateCylinder" function.
I using Delphi Xe2 and JEDI for DirectX9.

Comment: You all are not knowing what is Delphi and Jedi, so you should not close the question. Don’t CLOSE question for some reputation only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare direct3D Object, RenderingDevice and Mesh as global variable.
In order to use DirectX in the Delphi - Pascal, add Direct3D9, D3DX9, DXTypes in USES clause.

```
uses Winapi.Direct3D9, Winapi.D3DX9, Winapi.DXTypes;
```

Global Declaration:

```
const
   D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX = (D3DFVF_XYZ or D3DFVF_NORMAL);
var
   objD3D: IDirect3D9 = nil;
   dvcRender: IDirect3DDevice9 = nil;
   vbD3D: IDirect3DVertexBuffer9;
   mesh: ID3DXMesh;
```

Create Function for Initialization of Direct3D:

```
function TfrmDirectX.initD3D(hWindow: HWND): HRESULT;
var
   paramD3D: TD3DPresentParameters;
begin
   Result := E_FAIL;
   objD3D := Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
   if (objD3D = nil) then Exit;

   FillChar(paramD3D, SizeOf(paramD3D), 0);
   paramD3D.Windowed := True;
   paramD3D.SwapEffect := D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
   paramD3D.BackBufferFormat := D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
   paramD3D.EnableAutoDepthStencil := True;
   paramD3D.AutoDepthStencilFormat := D3DFMT_D16;
   Result := objD3D.CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWindow,
                             D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                             @paramD3D, dvcRender);
   if Failed(Result) then Exit;
   dvcRender.SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, iTrue);
   Result := S_OK;
end;
```

I will render 3D on TPanel component of the Delphi. So i passing Handle of TPanel Component as parameter.
Another Function to setup a Matrix:

```
procedure TfrmDirectX.setupMatrices();
var
   vEyePt, vLookatPt, vUpVec: TD3DVector;
   matView: TD3DMatrix;
   matProj: TD3DMatrix;
begin
   vEyePt:= D3DXVector3(spnCX.Value, spnCY.Value, spnCZ.Value);
   vLookatPt:= D3DXVector3(spnLX.Value, spnLY.Value, spnLZ.Value);
   vUpVec:= D3DXVector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(matView, vEyePt, vLookatPt, vUpVec);
   dvcRender.SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, matView);

   D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(matProj, D3DX_PI/4, 1.0, 1.0, 100.0);
   dvcRender.SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, matProj);
   mesh.DrawSubset(0);
end;
```

And Last procedure for Rendering:

```
procedure TfrmDirectX.render();
begin
   // Call function to create Cylinder and return Mesh.
   D3DXCreateCylinder(dvcRender, 1, 1, 2, 8, 8, mesh, nil);
   dvcRender.Clear(0, nil, D3DCLEAR_TARGET OR D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
              D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), 1.0, 0);
   if Succeeded(dvcRender.BeginScene) then begin
      setupMatrices();
      dvcRender.EndScene;
   end;
   dvcRender.Present(nil, nil, 0, nil);
end;
```

### D3DXCreateCylinder Function

Uses a left-handed coordinate system to create a mesh containing a cylinder.

Syntax

```
HRESULT D3DXCreateCylinder( LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice,
FLOAT Radius1,
FLOAT Radius2,
FLOAT Length,
UINT Slices,
UINT Stacks,
LPD3DXMESH *ppMesh,
LPD3DXBUFFER *ppAdjacency
);
```

Parameters:

pDevice
[in] Pointer to an IDirect3DDevice9 interface, representing the device associated with the created cylinder mesh.

Radius1
[in] Radius at the negative Z end. Value should be greater than or equal to 0.0f.

Radius2
[in] Radius at the positive Z end. Value should be greater than or equal to 0.0f.

Length
[in] Length of the cylinder along the z-axis.

Slices
[in] Number of slices about the main axis.

Stacks
[in] Number of stacks along the main axis.

ppMesh
[out] Address of a pointer to the output shape, an ID3DXMesh interface.

ppAdjacency
[out] Address of a pointer to an ID3DXBuffer interface. When the method returns, this parameter is filled with an array of three DWORDs per face that specify the three neighbors for each face in the mesh. NULL can be specified.

Return Value:
If the function succeeds, the return value is D3D_OK.

After Creating All the Function and Procedure first call InitD3D(hWindow) and then call Render().